# Conditional Format-Wide in pipelines

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I want to conditionally apply `Format-Wide` to a pipeline:

```
Get-ChildItem | Format-Wide
```

How can I make `| Format-Wide` part conditional on a variable? For example, apply `| Format-Wide` only if `$condition` is `True`.

Edited: the following is what I want to achieve:

```
function format-conditional {
  param ([bool]$condition)
  if ($condition) {$input | Format-Wide -Column 3 } 
  else {$input}
}

Invoke-Expression ("Get-ChildItem $Args") |
%{
    $fore = $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor
    $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = 'Green'
    echo $_
    $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = $fore
} | format-conditional $false
```

But with this the `Green` color is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create your own function for that if you want to do it in the pipeline:

```
function format-conditional
{
  param ([bool]$condition)
  if ($condition) {$input | format-wide } 
  else {$input}
}

 $test = $true

 gci | format-conditional $test
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This certainly solves the problem, except that when I apply this I lose the foreground color that I set. I added a snippet showing what I wanted, could you please comment on why I'm losing the color?

Comment: Nope.  That's a whole 'nother can of worms.